# What type of menu bar is this?

Tags: menu, menubar

I'm going to be building a CSS menu bar into a site much like the one at http://www.mightyleaftea.com

I've heard of dropdown menus, but what is the type of menu at mightleaftea.com called?
Oh, and more recently http://www.whitehouse.gov/

This is programming related.  I have to build the menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a regular hierarchical dropdown menu to me.

Try this [alistapart dropdowns article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns).

Answer (score 2):

It's look like some kind of [suckerfish](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a simple DHTML menu.

Basically all their doing is display setting of them menu div when you hover over the link.

something like:

```
document.getElementById('menu_div').style.display = 'block';
```

then on mouse out you would have

```
document.getElementById('menu_div').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dropdown menu using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would still call it a drop down menu. It just so happens that the drop-down part has more going on inside than a typical html list of links.

Answer (score 0):

Mega Menu or Mega Drop Down Menu